# How to add a diffrent background image to different div elements on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several div elements aligned in a grid. I want them to have their specific different background images when the user hovers over them which disappear when the mouse leaves the div. Basically it's a users information page where every square has the data of a user. When people hover over the squares, the users' images appear as background images. Here's the HTML:

```
<div class="contributor">
  Some great stuff here
</div>
```

Here's the jQuery code I'm currently using. The problem: It assigns the same image to every div while I want different images for each div.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.contributor').mouseenter(function(){
      $(this).addClass('visible');
  });
  $('.contributor').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).removeClass('visible');
});
```

});

Here's the code for the 'visible' class:

```
.visible{
  background-image: url('../res/dev-1.png');
}
```

Comment: use `$(this).css('background-image','../res/dev-1.png')` so that you can change the image contextually...

Comment: the problem is that you are setting statically the image for class `visible`. Then when a user hovers a div it displays the `visible` background-image, always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, save the image url in an attribute named "imageurl" (which isn't parsed by the browser):

```
<div class="contributor" imgageurl="../res/dev-1.png"></div>
<div class="contributor" imgageurl="../res/dev-2.png"></div>
```

Then, use this jQuery code:

```
$('.contributor').mouseenter(function(){
      var imgageUrl = $(this).attr("imageurl");
      $(this).css("background-image" , imgageUrl); 
  });
  $('.contributor').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image" , "none");
  });
```

Of course, you also have to build the HTML dynamically.

Comment: It's not good, you should use pure CSS for this effect. If you need to have image URL in HTML you should add inline style `background-image` and use pseudo-class `:hover` for change visibility `background-image'

Comment: @Whitcik first of all it's good because it works. Second, he cannot use pure CSS since the data is dynamic. You need to create a CSS file dynamically from server side in order to perform your solution. And finally, he asked for a jQuery solution. You can argue that it's not good to use jQuery at all and he better use Angular or another framework.

Comment: @Alon you can do it thanks inline style :) Jquery is ok, but when you can get the same effect using CSS, it will always be better :) Searching better solution that makes us better and better and better :)

Comment: @Whitcik Didn't think of it that way. I'll try that too. Thanks.

Comment: @Whitcik again, CSS is better as long as it's static. I rather have static JS code than a dynamic CSS file that I have to create from server side.

Answer (score 2):

Why do you use jQuery? use just CSS and pseudo-class `:hover`.

```
.contributor:hover{
  background-image: url('../res/dev-1.png');
}
```

apply for diffrent div:

```
.contributor.diff-div:hover{
  background-image: url('../res/dev-2.png');
}
```

If you can do something in the **CSS**, it is almost always it will be a **better solution** than using **JavaScript**

Comment: How can I aplly different images to different divs?

Comment: add ID's to the 2 divs and target them with css. Inside css for each div just use `background: url(../img/somepic.jpg);` **And remember: ID's always should be unique!**

Comment: @AdityaJGupta  Add auxiliary class, i updated asnwer

Comment: @Whitcik There are literally hundreds of users' data. I'll have to create hundreds of rules for adding images to all of them. Any ideas for adding the image based on the username as the image names and usernames are the same?

Answer (score 0):

may be you can consider `css` function instead of addClass.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.contributor').mouseenter(function(){
      if(this.id == "one")
         $(this).css("background-image" , "url('../res/dev-1.png')");
      else if(this.id == "two")
         $(this).css("background-image" , "url('../res/dev-2.png')");
  });
  $('.contributor').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css("background-image" , "none");
  });
});
```

Comment: The problem is the size of data. There are literally hundreds of users' data and creating an if-else case for all of them isn't feasible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with jquery. suppose you have six images from `dev-1.png` to `dev-6.png` then it will set them as bacground for div number 1 to 6 respectively

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.contributor').mouseover(function(){
     var index = $("div").index(this);
     index++;
     var bI= "background-image:url('../res/dev-"+index+".png');";
     $("this").eq(index).attr('style',bI);
  });
  $('.contributor').mouseleave(function(){
     var index = $("div").index(this);
     index++;
     var bI= "background-image:none";
     $("this").eq(index).attr('style',bI);
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

*For reference (Too troublesome and Won't apply if you have a ton of elements)*

**This can be achieved with pure CSS.**

*images might take a second to load (random image services)*

**Working example:** (**not responsive open in full page**)

```css
.optionlist li {
  background: #111;
  color: #999;
  padding: .5em;
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 1px solid;
  max-width: 70px
}
.optionlist li:hover {
  background: red;
}
.optionlist li:hover:after {
  content: '';
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
/* Start Background Control */

#red:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/600/)
}
#blue:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/601/)
}
#green:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/600/)
}
#yellow:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/601/)
}
#orange:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/799/600/)
}
#white:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/800/599/)
}
#black:after {
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/801/599/)
}
/* End Background Control */
```

```html
<div class="optionlist">
  <ul>
  <li id="red">Red</li>
  <li id="blue">Blue</li>
  <li id="green">Green</li>
  <li id="yellow">Yellow</li>
  <li id="orange">Orange</li>
  <li id="white">White</li>
  <li id="black">Black</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```